# How to sort and display only first occurrence of every unique lines in unix?

Tags: unix

How to sort and display only first occurrence of every unique lines in unix?

E.g.,
file contains:

abcd 5

abcd 2

abcd 10

xyz 1

xyz 4

xyz 5

Needed Output:

abcd 10

xyz 5

Edit:
I have abcd & xyz in column 1 multiple times with different values in column 2. All I need is sort -nk2 | head -1 of abcd & xyz or anything in column1 in the file.

Found a way to get this but anyone can update with better solution.
I can do awk column1, sort -u into file and then grep unique sorted column1 contents and do a sort -nk2 | head -1 to get the expected result.

Thanks,

Mak

Comment: Did you try sort file.log | uniq -u? This should work if the file contains lines (not space separated words as in your example). Btw, the "needed output" you provides is not default alphanumerical sorting. If you actually have space separated items or want custom sorting, this will complicate the command. Or is it two words a line? Consider improvong sample input and output.

Comment: @mak - Your question is nonsensical. An occurrence of a _unique line_ is the first, the last, the only occurrence.

Comment: @armali please follow the input and required output example if my explanation is not clear. I have abcd & xyz in column 1 multiple times with different values in column 2. All I need is sort -nk2 | head -1 of abcd & xyz or n number of lines in the file.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you can't be bothered to correct inconsistencies (not just ambiguities) in your question, I'm not inclined to look for an answer.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that in the "Edit" in the question or some of these comment answers, the OP is using a unix command (`sort -nk2 | head -1 of abcd & xyz`) to ask for what they want a unix command to do. It's like saying, "I just want know how to do `ls` in unix". Either you want `ls` (and thus you have your answer) or you actually want something else (and you should describe that (in English) without resorting to commands that don't work for you).

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk '{ map[$1][$2]=1 } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";for (i in map) { for (j in map[i]) { } print i " "j } }' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk '{ 
       map[$1][$2]=""                                  # Create a 2 dimensional array with the first space separated field as the first index and the second field the second index
     } 
 END {                                                 # Process at the end of the file
       PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";           # Set the array ordering Iindex ascending)
       for (i in map) { 
         for (j in map[i]) { 
         } 
         print i " "j                                  # Loop through the array printing the result
       } 
      }' file
```

Comment: Hi Raman, Thanks for your effort. I'm seeing syntax issues with your script. rectified one issue but not able to do other one.

Comment: What version of awk are you using. This works fine with GNU awk 4.2